# App Insights reporting result code 208 for SQL dependency

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

My application made in ASP.Net core is using EF 6.1.
I keep receiving warning message from App Insights while n-log does not show anything unusual.
What is this 208 code from SQL and why does App Insights log this as exception?

[image: exception screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a list of messages (SELECT * FROM SYS.MESSAGES) the exception you get is "Invalid object name".
Check the spelling or default schema or schema name.